# How to use twitter ads api for twitter ads campaign's performance in react native

Tags: react-native, mobile, twitter, instagram-api, google-ads-api

I want to use the Twitter Ads API in my React Native project to track the performance of my Twitter advertising campaign, but I couldn't find many resources on the internet. Do you know of any documentation or YouTube video that can help me with this? Or can you explain it to me?